# Dynamic mask rules for fields using jquery in a ASP NET MVC app

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, mask

I just wan´t a second opinion

I have a form that enable users creates some indexes. I need to add a mask functionality. Users will be able to create its own field mask based on a rule. I am thinking of stores that mask in a database table like that:

```
id -> index id
idName -> as for example: phoneNumber
mask -> (999) - 9999-9999
```

The second step would be retrieve the mask and associate it with the index field using javascript

```
$('#idName').mask(mask);
```

Would be that a good approach or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found to configure the field mask dinamycally is to get the mask from a input field, and use it inside of a mask function

```
mask = $('#mask').val();
$('#idName').mask(mask);
```

Worked for me. Tks